# SQL GROUP BY and create Element for each GROUP

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-insert, orientdb

**UPDATE:**
I was able to solve this with `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO newClass
FROM
    SELECT newClassID AS id, newClassName AS name
    FROM oldClass
GROUP BY newClassID
```

---

I'm using SQL with Orient DB version 2.2.
I want to group element of one class by attribute `newClassID` (there are multiple Elements in this class that share `newClassID`, lets say I have 20 Elements in the first class and 3 unique `newClassID`). Each group will have unique `newClassID`and also `newClassName` as these attributes go hand in hand.
For each group I want to create an element of another Class (`newClass`), that will have the `id = newClassID and name = newClassName`. In the above case this will result to 3 new Elements in the `newClass`.

The Elelemt of the first class would look like:

| Elem | newClassID | newClassName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id1 | name1 |
| 2 | id2 | name2 |
| 3 | id1 | name1 |
| 4 | id3 | name3 |
| 5 | id2 | name2 |

And I wand to create 3 new elements in new Class:

| Elem | ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id1 | name1 |
| 2 | id2 | name2 |
| 3 | id3 | name3 |

With this query I get id and name as attributes:

```
BEGIN
    let pattern = SELECT newClassID, newClassName
                  FROM oldClass GROUP BY newClassID
COMMIT
RETURN { 'id' : $pattern.newClassID, 'name' : $pattern.newClassName }
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "name": [
            "name1",
            "name2",
            "name3"
        ],
        "id": [
            "id1",
            "id2",
            "id3"
        ],
        "@fieldTypes": "name=e,id=e"
    }
]
```

Now I want to call this function (called `GetNewClass()`) and create for each entry in id a `newClassElement`. I can not use `FOREACH` as this is just available from version 3.x . To be honest: here I have no clue how to do this..

I tried:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO newClass FROM SELECT GetNewClass()
let newElements = SELECT FROM newClass
RETURN $newElements
```

But this gives me just one element with:

```
[
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#41:1",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "newClass",
        "GetProdID": {
            "name": [
                "name1",
                "name2",
                "name3"
            ],
            "id": [
                "id1",
                "id2",
                "id3"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know anything about Oriend DB but I wanted to point out that from an SQL perspective using GROUP BY has no effect if you are not doing some calculation like SUM or COUNT. So `SELECT newClassID, newClassName FROM oldClass` will yield the same result. (unless newClassID is not unique)

Comment: Exactly, newClassID is not unique - I ill add this to the post

Comment: Ok but then I think it is better to use `SELECT DISTINCT...` to avoid confusion